# Which controller to use in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to create a controller that should run a till the condition fails. How it can be implemented in Jmeter.

The controller should contain a HTTP Request with a post body which is dynamic the request should continue till the condition fails,but i dont know where the should i apply that condition.

```
{
  "access": {
    "identifier": "9876f",
    "Reproduce": "Right",
    "possible": {
      "id": "u7ur038",
      "value": "Move"
    }
  }
}
```

If the response  `"Reproduce"` contain `"Right"`then it should run again HTTP Request for new body and If the response  `"Reproduce"` contain `"Wrong"`then it should stop executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) which will contain your request.

Condition of While Controller will be:

> ${__jexl3("${response}" != "Wrong")}

Add as child of your HTTP Request a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

- Names of created variables: response
- JSON Path Expressions: $..Reproduce
- Match No.: 1

To reset variable for next thread loop iteration, add before While Controller a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) and put inside it a preprocessor called [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) .

Click « Add Variable » and set :

- Name: response
- User_1: Right

Comment: can you  tell how to extract x value using token extractor ```{
"access" :[
    {"x":"1234566","c":"qwer"},
    {"y":"12344532566","b":"asdf"},
    {"z":"12358b2","a":"zxcv"}
]
}```

Comment: i tried this ```$.access[1].x``` but when i log it prints the value for me as null

Comment: If it’s another question, please accept this one and upvote if ok and open another one, thanks.

Comment: Hi @UBIK LOAD PACK while using ```While Controller``` there is a problem Thread Group Loop Count does not work in this case.

Comment: Hi @ UBIK LOAD PACK In Thread Group ,  i am not able to use ```Loop Count``` parameter to infinite because  When while controller condition ```${__jexl3("${response}" != "Wrong")}``` is met it stops. and does not go for loop count

Comment: can you show how While Controller is inside Thread group ? thanks

Comment: i did not understand can you elaborate more ? thanks